# Installing Tridion Reference Implementation - Web Application Error - Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

Tags: 2013, dxa

I am trying to run Reference Implementation but can't seem to get past my web application error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2014-09-17 12:20:08,156 [1] ERROR - <JavaException>
<Type>java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError</Type>
<Message><![CDATA[Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
```

ClassPath           : C:\Training_Development\websites\staging\bin\bin

I can see the double '\bin\bin' reference, which my application does not have but I am unsure where this is set.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: This is a "generic" Tridion error, looks like there was no configured CD environment before you installed the Reference Implementation?

Comment: Another symptom associated with this issue was that I could not publish the Structure Group but I could publish individual items okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this error for a multitude of reasons, none of which have anything to do with the fact that it says bin/bin, which is a bit of a misleading message. As Nuno comments its a general CD configuration issue, nothing specific to the Reference Implementation. Did you already have a working CD environment? It could be an invalid or missing license, missing jar files in your bin/lib directory, or even Java compatibility issues - I have only used the Reference Implementation with Java 7 - if you are not using this version, it may be that there is some compatibility issue with tridion or 3rd party jars in the example web app, or loaded from somewhere your CLASSPATH (if set).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Will and Nuno, you got me on the right track.  It seems the problem was because I was using MVC3 instead of MVC5.  After upgrading it worked fine.

Comment: We are working on a hotfix to sort this out - the MVC dlls will be added to the bin directory of the site