# DXA 1.2 OOB Installation issues

Tags: dxa

1. Unable to publish all pages from Home StructureGroup. Other than "Internal Server Error", there is not much useful information from the logs for these failures. However, most of the other files publish successfully into the DB.

Log Snippet cd_core.log - 
2015-11-27 11:01:51,325 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to send TransportPackage to url: https:///HTTPUpload.aspx cause: Internal Server Error

2. When trying to access the DXA OOB installed site, it throws the following error - Internal Server error.

Log Snippet from site.log -

2015-11-27 10:43:20,760 [9] ERROR - 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2015-11-27 10:43:20,825 [9] ERROR - Internal Server Error

## System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error ---> Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Error loading binary for URL '/version.json' ---> Java.Lang.Throwable: Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

```
ClassPath           : D:\Inetpub\DXARef\bin\bin
```

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPARatingDAO
  com.tridion.validation.adapter.ContentValidatorSpringAdapter
  com.tridion.validation.ValidationFacade
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Rating
  com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
  com.tridion.validation.ValidationException
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCValidationFacade
  com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Comment
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAUserDAO
  com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp$Error
  com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleCommentingValidator
  com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
  com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleRatingValidator
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPACommentDAO
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
  com.tridion.deployer.Deployer
  com.tridion.ugc.Status
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAItemStatsDAO
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCConfigurationLoader
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.User
  com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.ItemStats
  [Lcom.tridion.ugc.Status;
  com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Item
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.RatingDAO
  com.tridion.validation.ContentValidator
  com.tridion.validation.Errors
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.UserDAO
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.CommentDAO
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.ItemStatsDAO

at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
   at Com.Tridion.Meta.BinaryMetaFactory.GetMetaByURL(Int32 publicationId, String urlPath)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.BinaryMetaFactory.GetMetaByUrl(Int32 publicationId, String urlPath)
   at DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013sp1.TridionBinaryProvider.GetBinaryByUrl(String url) in D:\DD4T\DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013sp1\source\DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013sp1\TridionBinaryProvider.cs:line 120
   at DD4T.Factories.BinaryFactory.TryFindBinary(String url, IBinary& binary) in D:\DD4T\DD4T.Core\source\DD4T.Factories\BinaryFactory.cs:line 42
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Statics.BinaryFileManager.GetCachedFile(String urlPath, Localization localization) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Statics\BinaryFileManager.cs:line 154
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Statics.BinaryFileManager.GetCachedFile(String urlPath, Localization localization) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Statics\BinaryFileManager.cs:line 180
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultProvider.GetStaticContentItem(String urlPath, Localization localization) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultProvider.cs:line 152
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.Load() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\Localization.cs:line 215
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.EnsureInitialized() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\Localization.cs:line 139
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdConfigLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdConfigLocalizationResolver.cs:line 81
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 23
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 50
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2015-11-27 10:43:24,584 [11] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 92
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2015-11-27 10:43:24,586 [8] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 92
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2015-11-27 10:43:24,620 [5] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 92
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2015-11-27 10:43:24,655 [12] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 92
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2015-11-27 10:43:24,690 [10] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 92
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2015-11-27 10:43:24,933 [12] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:24,934 [11] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:24,935 [5] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:24,936 [10] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:24,936 [8] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:24,969 [10] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:24,971 [8] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:24,971 [12] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:24,972 [5] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:24,972 [11] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error
2015-11-27 10:43:25,211 [10] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 92
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2015-11-27 10:43:25,213 [10] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error

All the paths that were mentioned like Jenkins, DD4T doesn't exist in my server. Am I missing any required DLLs/jars?
I haven't built the site from the code. Just installed OOB sample site from DXA Installer.

Comment: Check your licence files

Comment: The source file paths are the paths as they are on the DXA build server. You can ignore those.  Most likely cause of such error is missing CD license file or database drivers, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The following message is a fairly generic message when encountering problems with your Content Delivery (CD) environment:

> Some configured classpath roots cannot be found. ClassPath: D:\Inetpub\DXARef\bin\bin

Some things that you might want to check are:

1. Is your Tridion license file valid (as suggested by Rob and Rick above)
2. Do you have the correct database driver (e.g. `jdbc4.jar`) installed for your web application? (As mentioned by Rick)
3. Are you using the correct Java version in the CD environment?
4. Does your web app use the correct Microsoft .NET Framework version (v4.5.1)?
5. Are you using the correct version of MVC (as also described [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/7922/71))?

Although no longer available on [the SDL Documentation Centre](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?action=html&resource=publist_home.html), you can still get to the DXA v1.2 documentation here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v2&lang=en-US